Is consciousness a means of our species or a consequence of accumulated knowledge?
Consciousness for me is you being conscious of being in a body. It separates from the human body, for me, consciousness is the "being" of the "human being". So, is it a means of our species or a consequence?
EDIT: Going a little further. Since I quoted the "birth" of consciousness, I would like to say about the "death" of it. One hypothesis I have is that consciousness arose as a way for our species to preserve itself, since the preservation of the body itself is a natural law of the universe. Consciousness emerges as a way of contemplating reality and thinking about it, and then people began to "prolong their lives/consience" using art forms: Paintings, Films, Books, etc. And so consciousness is used to preserve the species, there is no way to "kill" the consciousness of someone, he is at the heart of the work of this person, prolonging his life.
That’s my idea of why it came about, but I still don’t know how it came about.
(Using Reverso Text)

Are you looking for conclusions based on your stated opinions, or the conclusions of any well-known theories of mind?

Looking at your opinions, it may be what you believe or any theories. But remaining in the subject: The emergence of consciousness. Is it something that our body has developed manually, or is it a consequence of storing knowledge?
